# Update an existing card with Twilio <Pay>

Tags: stripe-payments, twilio

I have a service accessed by telephone for people with no internet. When a customer signs up they can subscribe to the premium service with a card over the phone. But I am not able to figure out a way to have the customer be able to update or replace their card over the phone using the twilio  voice verb with a Stripe payment connector. This is how I have it when a customer first creates their account

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Calling Twilio Pay</Say>   
  <Pay chargeAmount="0.00"/>
</Response>
```

This creates a blank customer in Stripe and returns the customer code. I then attach that code to the customer in my database. And update the Stripe customer with the information I had on my end. (email, phone, name, and address if available). This I do with the C# Stripe SDK. Now, I want to update a customer card on an existing Stripe customer ID. So far I have not been able to. By using the above method, I have tried attaching the card from the new stripe customer ID to my existing one, but that isn't allowed. I tried detaching the card from the new stripe customer, then try to attach it to the original one, but detaching seems to be the same as deleting. What I need is a way to pass in a StripeCustomer ID with the Pay connector, using something like a chargeCustomer parameter for example.

```
  <Pay chargeAmount="0.00" chargeCustomer="cus_k36nf92bhss/>
```

If there is already a way to update I would be thrilled to know!